# How can I find and edit the html code for Moodle without using the additional HTML box?

Tags: moodle, moodle-theme

I've been hunting for days now and for whatever reason the code seems to be pretty elusive with files linking to files that link to other files that don't exist. So can anyone tell me where i can find the HTML / PHP / SQL code, or whatever it may be, that is used to piece together the course?

The section im trying to edit is this red block:

[image: this red block]

Looking at the browser developer tools the div is called page-header. But more realistically it could be called something completely different in the madness that pieces it all together.

After some digging i came across `drawers.mustche` in boost / templates / and on line 129 it says `{{{ output.full.header}}}`

[image: {{{ output.full.header}}}]

but i get lost from there because there doesn't seem to be any file that remotely references the full header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In moodle, you can use the theme plugin renderers to render the core outputs.
Please refer to the theme renderer method.
https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Overriding_a_renderer

you can find the full_header function in **lib\outputrenderers.php** Line no 4340.
Html content of the full header loaded from **lib\templates\full_header.mustache**

You can override the full_header HTML content using the currently running theme.
The following steps will help you to change the full header.

1. Create the folder "core" in the current running theme "templates" folder.
   i.e **theme\boost\templates\core**
2. Copy the **full_header.mustache** from the lib\templates folder to the newly created theme\template\core folder.
3. Do the changes in the **theme\templates\full_header.mustache** file
4. Clear the cache in **Site admin > development > purge caches**